# DAX Joint value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure in DAX to find the joint value (sum) of a fact table by filtering two dimension tables to have the same column value.

Here's an image of the relationship

[image]

Each Department in `Users` are linked to table `Registret`. They are giving resources to projects. The table `Projects` are Taking Resourcs. What I am trying to accomplish is a measure that can find the amount a department uses of it's own resources. So I figure if I can filter `Registret[Users]` and `Registre[Project]` where `Users[Department`] = `Projects[Department]` I would get the value.

I'd like to use the `Projects[Department]` as a basis. So that table below would show the amount of internal department registration by each `Department` in `Projects`.

```
Department(Projects)   InternalRegistration
   A                           Value 
   B                           Value
```

So far I've been trying with something like

```
CALCULATE(Registret[Registret]; FILTER(Users; Users[Department] IN ALLSELECTED(Projects[Departments])))
```

But this will only show the correct value if I in a slicer single out a Department from table `Projects`. Is it possible the solution is some Joint table between `Users` and `Projects`?

Edit: 
[image]

The top table shows the matrix of joint values in `Registret` between `Users` and `Projects`.

Edit2:

[image]
Image of my table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the filter arrows only point downward. This means that selecting `Projects[Departments]` isn't going to filter `Users[Departments]` since there is no filter path connecting them. You are also missing the `SUM` function in your measure.

Try tweaking your measure to the following:

```
= CALCULATE(SUM(Registret[Registret]);
      FILTER(Users; Users[Department] = SELECTEDVALUE(Projects[Departments])))
```

If you're working in a matrix or a table, the `SELECTEDVALUE` should pick up the row/column filter context from the visual, whereas `ALLSELECTED` only picks up filter context from slicers or report/page/visual level filters.

---

You can also use `...IN VALUES(...` instead of `...= SELECTEDVALUE(...`.

```
= CALCULATE(SUM(Registret[Registret]),
      FILTER(Users, Users[Department] IN VALUES(Projects[Department])))
```

---

Both of these should produce the following:

[image: Matrix]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am getting a "the function expects a table expression for argument 2, but a string or numeric expression was used" error. Not sure what to make of it since the 2nd argument in SELECTEDVALUE is optional?

Comment: I forgot to replace the `IN` with an `=` (`IN` expects a table, but `SELECTEDVALUE` returns one value).

Comment: It gives the same result as just putting the registret value in the value. I've updated the post with an image. The column 'Test 2' on the second table is the DAX you provided. I were hoping it would show 10 :)

Comment: Can you post what your tables so I can try to reproduce this?

Comment: I added them as an image. I don't know if there's an easier way to share them(?) - Thanks alot for helping!

Comment: That's fine for small tables. If you have a lot more data, typically you'd post it in text form.

Comment: Ah, I missed the `SUM` part. The dangers of trying to write code outside of the actual environment. Please see my edit.

Comment: it works perfectly! Thanks again for all your help. Greatly appreciated :)